# Get access to the params while saving virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have model `Countries`. And I have associated model `Regions`. `Regions` belongs_to `Countries` and have country_id field. And I have model `Objects`, which associated with `Country` and `Region`. But, in the form, user types their names, so I have virtual attributes `country_name` and `region_name`, and I parse then in model. So, country saves in Countries and region in Regions. But how when I'm saving Region, to assign `country_id` to Region model? I can not get access to params from model, so what can I do?

Comment: Would you be able to include an example of your code (the models and associations)? Then the problem would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was easy.

```
def region_name=(name)
region = Region.find_or_create_by(:name => name, :country_id => Country.find_by(:name => self.country_name).id) if name.present?
self.region_id = region.id
end
```